# How comment can execute?

Tags: javascript, comments

In my code i wrote this code for popup
but the commented line

`// mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');`

automatically executed.Why?
and if i deleted this line my page don't show any error.
if it is present as comment it shows an error that duplicate title tag.

```
 function Popup(data) {
            var mywindow = window.open('', 'mydiv', 'height=400,width=600');
           // mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
            /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
            mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
            mywindow.document.write(data);
            mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            mywindow.document.close();
            mywindow.print();
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: How can you tell it executed? Do you pass the code through some tool before uploading to the server?

Comment: it executed and threw error of duplicate title in page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you executed it on the server and then commented it, the server might have cached your old js file... try to pass a parameter (any) to the js file in the  tag: `<script src="myfile.js?version=1.0"/>`

Comment: no such issues every time it is run from new server and also i've checked by clearing the browser history and also if i deleted this line it run fine?

Comment: That's really strange. Now I suspect one thing that happened to me once, but in different circumstances: I was coding in ActionScript for Flex and I had one comment that, once deleted, caused the application to crash. So, I had to leave it, but with a comment: "Do not delete" :)
The next version of ActionScript worked fine even without this comment. 

My point: try different browsers. In my chrome this comment works as it should (once commented, I have "Untitled", when I remove the comment, I get "my div"). So, in my opinion it is the browser's bug.